# How to get a text from a ListView item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

`listview.item[x].Text` returns `"ListViewItem: {item's text}"` but i want only text

for example, item 0= a.txt

`listView1.Items[0].Text`  =>  `"ListViewItem: {a.txt}"`

why not `"a.txt"`?

where is the problem?

Comment: `where is the problem` - for starters the way you ask questions. To fix this problem you may read the following article: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: The [text] tag and the [item] tag are not useful. However, a [winforms], [asp.net], [wpf] tag or another appropriate tag describing the technology you are using would be helpful, since there are different kinds of listviews around.

Answer (score 1):

Many .NET classes, like ListViewItem, override the System.Object.ToString() method.  Which looks like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "ListViewItem: {" + this.Text + "}";
}
```

So clearly you are using listView1.Items[0] and not listView1.Items[0].Text in your code or debug watch expression.  It isn't clear which applies from the question.

Comment: my code ise `listView1.Items[0].Text` and returns 
    `"ListViewItem: {" + this.Text + "}`

Comment: I flat out don't believe that.  Post a screenshot to prove it.

Comment: My listview.items[0].text shows the aforementioned as well